# Creating JS Object with methods from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need the following object:

```
var myObj={
    "rules": {
        "email": {
            "required": true,
            "email": true,
            "remote": {
                "url": "check-email.php",
                "type": "post",
                "data": {
                    "someName1": function() {
                        return $( '#someID1' ).val();
                    },             
                    "someName2": function() {
                        return $( '#someID2' ).val();
                    },             
                    "someName3": "bla"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To create it, I only have some JSON such as the following:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "email": {
            "required": true,
            "email": true,
            "remote": {
                "url": "check-email.php",
                "type": "post",
                "data": {
                    "someName1": {"id":"someID1"},             
                    "someName2": {"id":"someID2"},             
                    "someName3": "bla"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "rules": {
        "email": {
            "required": true,
            "email": true,
            "remote": {
                "url": "check-email.php",
                "type": "post",
                "data": {
                    "someName1": {"function":"return $( '#someID1' ).val()"},             
                    "someName2": {"function":"return $( '#someID2' ).val()"},             
                    "someName3": "bla"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or something similar.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Function` to create functions on the fly. Supposing you have the second JSON structure:

```
d = obj.rules.email.remote.data;
Object.keys(d).forEach(function(key) {
    d[key] = new Function(d[key].function); 
    //Note: You might want to check if d[key].function exists before using it.
});
```

Comment: Thanks Thrustmaster.  I will test it out.

Comment: Also works.  https://jsfiddle.net/e4hq2w1b/4/ or without creating a new variable https://jsfiddle.net/e4hq2w1b/5/.  Note that I was unable to use `function` as a property name.

Answer (score 2):

For this pattern :

```
{
    "rules": {
        "email": {
            "required": true,
            "email": true,
            "remote": {
                "url": "check-email.php",
                "type": "post",
                "data": {
                    "someName1": {"id":"someID1"},             
                    "someName2": {"id":"someID2"},             
                    "someName3": "bla"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can be done as:

```
for(var key in myObj.rules.email.remote.data){
    if(myObj.rules.email.remote.data[key].id){
    myObj.rules.email.remote.data[key] = function(){
          return $('#'+myObj.rules.email.remote.data[key].id).val();
        }
    }
}
```

if email is not hardcoded then it can be done as:

```
for(var key1 in myObj.rules){
 for(var key in myObj.rules[key1].remote.data){
        if(myObj.rules[key1].remote.data[key].id){
        myObj.rules[key1].remote.data[key] = function(){
              return $('#'+myObj.rules[key1].remote.data[key].id).val();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad for not being more specific.  What if `email` can't be hardcoded, and the same should happen to any with a similar pattern?  Pattern being `*.rules.*.remote.data`.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav,  Let me try it out.

Comment: Thanks weird.  `console.log` shows `rules.email.remote.data.someName1` as a function even before it is converted???  Still testing.  Thanks  https://jsfiddle.net/e4hq2w1b/1/

Comment: Doesn't work:  https://jsfiddle.net/e4hq2w1b/2/.  But then changed to declare `id` is a variable and it does: https://jsfiddle.net/e4hq2w1b/3/.  Do you know why the difference?

Comment: Actually, the later example still doesn't work as it always returns the value of the last (i.e. will return the value in `#someID2`).