# Browser support for JavaScript's Function() Constructor

Tags: javascript, oop

Does anyone know how well supported JavaScript's Function() Constructor is for older browsers?

```
var returnSomeID=new Function("return Document.getElementById('someID')"));
```

Comment: [MDN Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Browser_compatibility) for `Function`

Comment: It's been there since the language was introduced. Do you suspect that it's not working in some particular browser?

Comment: Also the code you're passing to the constructor is (probably) wrong. It (probably) should be `document` not `Document`.

Comment: Also also that's not a good way to create a function. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JamesThorpe  I looked there before posting this question.  It says IE, but not what versions.  IE6?

Comment: @Pointy  I am having no problems with the browsers I am using, but wanted to know whether it will work with older browsers.

Comment: @Pointy  I wish to create a JavaScript object with methods from JSON.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31933588/1032531 for history.

Comment: From what I understand, if it says "(yes)", it's been there from the start in that browser.  Compare to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) for instance where it lists specific versions of the browsers it was introduced with.

Comment: Ah OK well that'd be a good example of when `Function()` is useful :)

Comment: `From what I understand...`  When I assume, I usually assume wrong!  Thank you for the clarification.